# Any .net collection which has complexity of 0(1) or O(Logn) for look up and remove, add and insert

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, observablecollection

I am running into a very strange situation, I have created a class ObservableList It looks like as following

```
class observableList<T>:IObservableList<T>, IList, IUserCollectionType 
{

  private List<T> _list;

  private HashSet<T> _containedElements

// for each operation add,insert,remove I keep HashSet and List in synch.
}
```

}

I need HashSet for fast lookup but HashSet is not ordered collection and I need list because I need to raise CollectionChanged event but it requires index of item. So,for ordering I had to take list and for fast look up I had to take HashSet,

But Now, I am running into an issue that Removal from list is taking O(n). first I had to get index and then use removeAt() method, I had to get index because I had to raise collection changed event.

Now, I am looking for a solution that has complexity of O(1) or O(Logn) for lookup as well as removal has ordering as well as.
I can't use dicitonary because if I take index as key, and remove any item, then I have to update the Key of items by 1.

**So, why don't we have collection which has complexity of either O(1) or near

**1. For Lookup

 2. For Removal, add and insert.

 3. collection should be ordered**

In Java, someone told me that probably there is a class Linkedhashmap but I am not sure about that.  So, does .NET have an alternate for this collection.

or do we have any open source library which does have collection like that.

Comment: I think you can use SortedList. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately removal from a SortedList is O(N)

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible to have an *ordered* collection with O(1) complexity for insertion or removal.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I am also aware of that but is there any workaround or anything......

Comment: Alex, it does not need to be only O(1) everything appreciated which is lesser than O(N)

Comment: I don't think .NET provides a collection like that out of the box. But you can look up some binary tree implementation. O(longN) complexities for most operation if I recall correctly (if the tree is balanced). Or you can look at the red-black tree. It's a little more complicated, but it's self balancing.

Comment: Depending on HOW the collection should be ordered, you might be able to get what you want with a combination of `LinkedList` and a `Dictionary` which associates `LinkedListNode`s with the key. Lookup is via the `Dictionary` (~O(1)), removal by key or known node is similarly efficient, removal by value not so much. Insertion at front, back, or before/after a known key or node is O(1), but a *sorted* insert would be slow again. So if you want to e.g. preserve insertion order, that should work.

Comment: @Medo42 I need to preserve insertion order, could you please elaborate your answer or could give any reference link

Comment: I'll try to turn this into an answer then. :)

Comment: Ok that would be good

Comment: Also this might be of interest (depending on your intended usage pattern): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO

Comment: I think @Attila might be on the right track that it's possible to solve this with a custom tree structure (including efficient indexing), but before you try to go to such lengths, you should probably benchmark how much impact the O(n) operations really have on your application. Unless your list has tens of thousands of elements and/or is modified constantly, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: I elaborated on the tree structure idea a bit in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the performance that you are asking for by building something similar to Java's `LinkedHashSet` out of .Net's `LinkedList<T>` and `Dictionary<K,V>` classes. This can give you O(1) lookup, insert and remove, as well as preserving the insertion order.

I'm sketching this solution below; Note that this leaves out issues such as checking for duplicate elements, or actually implementing the IObservableList portion and some additional methods you might want. Also note that this is basically pseudocode, I didn't compile or test it.

```
class LinkedHashSet<T>
{
    private LinkedList<T> _list;
    private Dictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>> _containedElements

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> newNode = _list.AddLast(value);
        _containedElements[value] = newNode;
    }

    public void Remove(T value)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> node = _containedElements[value];
        _containedElements.Remove(value);
        _list.Remove(node);
    }

    public bool Contains(T value)
    {
        return _containedElements.ContainsKey(value);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Solving the whole problem**

As I already said in the comments, I noticed that the above isn't a complete solution to the question, since the question also refers to an additional operation: Finding the index in the list for a given item (at least in the context of removal).

I don't have a solution for that entirely worked out, but I do have an idea that might work, so here it is to make this answer a bit more complete:

You could replace the `LinkedList` in the example above with a balanced binary tree structure (e.g. a Red-Black tree). Every node in this tree references a value (just like every node in the linked list does), and every node also stores the count of its descendands in the tree.

You can find any element by its index `i` in O(log(n)) time by descending from the root and keeping at most `i` nodes to your left. Since each node helpfully tells you the count of its descendands, you only need to look at the left child of each node you encounter to find out if you need to continue left or right (or if the current node contains your target).

Inserting or removing elements is done as usual in a Red-Black tree, except that you need to update the descendand counts in all affected nodes and their ancestors. I didn't work this part out entirely, but I'm pretty sure this should still be possible in O(log(n)) time just as in a "normal" Red-Black tree.

Finally, you can find the index of any element in O(log(n)) time by starting at its node and walking up the tree, counting all the nodes on your left (again making use of the descendand count in each node). The node itself would be referenced by the Dictionary in the example above, so that you could actually find it efficiently.

**In summary**, replacing the `LinkedList` in the above example with the tree data structure described here would give you O(log(n)) insertion, removal, index lookup by value and value lookup by index, O(1) traversal (amortized), and O(1) contains check, all assuming that the Dictionary operations work with O(1).

Comment: List<T>.Remove() is O(n).  It calls IndexOf(object) then calls RemoveAt(index).

Comment: Not quite; There are two overloads of Remove(), and I use the one which takes a LinkedListNode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/43ttx77w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: you are right.  I'm going to leave my comment since your response is useful for others.